# How to return search results from solr extension in typo3?

Tags: search, solr, typo3

I am trying to use the plugin for the solr extension in typo 3 and as per [these instructions](http://forge.typo3.org/projects/extension-solr/wiki/Setup_the_Solr_Extension) everything went without a hitch except now no results are returned for any queries. I did check the list module and found devlog warning messages for: **No TYPO3SEARCH markers found. called from class.tx_solr_typo3pagecontentextractor.php line 91.**
Anyhelp regarding this would be appreciated. The following is a snapshot of the  [apache solr index report](http://imgur.com/nO5yL)
Thanks

Comment: what version of extension solr are you using? AFAIK the last version does not use frontend indexing any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to have those comments in your site:

```
<!--TYPO3SEARCH_begin-->
   .... content
<!--TYPO3SEARCH_end-->
```

The tell the solr extension what is the content, so it does not index your menu, header or footer. You may have multiple markers `TYPO3SEARCH_begin/end` in your template.

Comment: I'm using solr version 3.5.0 and those markers were already in the template file. Could it be that the reason I am not returning any result is due to folder permissions? the typo3 site folder is set to r-x for group and all else and the folder is owned by apache web server group.

Comment: Do I need to add markers to the template of the result page in order for solr to know where to print the results of the return query? I should also add that adding this markers doesn't seem to have solved the problem. I still have the warning in dev log.

Comment: You better ask on the TYPO3 Solr mailing list: http://lists.typo3.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/typo3-project-solr

Comment: Also correction the search markers are <!--TYPO3SEARCH_begin--> and <!--TYPO3SEARCH_end-->

Comment: I am sorry, I fixed it now. Can you please mark the answer as correct now?